# Opengl Camera * Projection * Coord = Nothing

Tags: opengl, matrix, lwjgl, projection

I have the following code to initialize my two matrices in lwjgl:

```
GL20.glUseProgram(shaderProgramID);
        Matrix4f camera = new Matrix4f();
        Matrix4f.translate(new Vector3f(0, 0, 0), camera, camera);
        FloatBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
        camera.store(buffer);
        buffer.flip();
        GL20.glUniformMatrix2(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramID, "camera"), false, buffer);
        GL20.glUseProgram(0);

        float near = 0.1f, far = 100.0f, top = 300, bottom = -300, left = -400, right = 400;  
        Matrix4f projection = new Matrix4f();
        projection.setIdentity();
        projection.m00 = 2*near/(right - left);
        projection.m11 = 2*near/(top - bottom);
        projection.m22 = -(far +near)/(far - near);
        projection.m23 = -1;
        projection.m32 = -2*far*near/(far - near);
        projection.m20 = (right+left)/(right -left);
        projection.m21 = (top + bottom)/(top-bottom);
        projection.m33 = 0;
        FloatBuffer buffer2 = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
        projection.store(buffer2);
        buffer.flip();
        GL20.glUniformMatrix2(GL20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgramID, "projection"), false, buffer);
        GL20.glUseProgram(0);
```

The vertex shader does the following:

```
gl_Position = projection * camera * vec4(vert, 1);
```

I dont know what could be wrong with it... anyone an idea?

Comment: If your `Matrix4f` class has a function called `setIdentity (...)` and this is not an operation performed upon construction, then why are you only calling it for your projection matrix? It would make sense to translate an ***identity*** camera matrix too.

Comment: its not my class its from org.lwjgl.util ... yeah it has the method setIdentity() but was does this actually mean? I added it to camery too, but it didnt help...

Comment: `setIdentity (...)` sets up the matrix so that it has the value **1.0** across the main diagonal (`m00`, `m11`, `m22`, `m33`) and all other values are **0.0**. Most importantly, this assigns **1.0** to `m33`. For proper translation and scaling, that is important and often overlooked.

Comment: yeah i found this in the source code from Matrix4f too. But also i've seen that the constructor of this class calls setIdentity(), so it doesnt make sense to call it again... so this cannot be the mistake...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is late but for completenesse's sake:

The code above leaves no program bound when glUseProgram(0): is called, thus the later call of glUniform* creates a GL_INVALID_OPERATION as there is no program oject present. This also means that projection is never actually set for your program, so upon rendering it is an empty matrix which multiplied with a matrix and a vector still results in the null vector.

Also you might consider saving the uniform locations once after loading the shader and check if it actually is available.